# Using KeyBERT to extract keywords and key terms from a CSV file

Tags: python, extract, keyword, bert-language-model

I was wondering if it's possible to apply KeyBERT to a relatively large Twitter dataset (from 1 to 12 million words). I tried forcing it to read a CSV file but it returned no keywords, literally "None". Below is the original code from its author. I'd be grateful if somebody could help me adapt it to extract keywords from a Twitter dataset.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from typing import List, Union, Tuple
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# KeyBERT
from keybert._mmr import mmr
from keybert._maxsum import max_sum_similarity
from keybert._highlight import highlight_document
from keybert.backend._utils import select_backend


class KeyBERT:
"""
A minimal method for keyword extraction with BERT

The keyword extraction is done by finding the sub-phrases in
a document that are the most similar to the document itself.

First, document embeddings are extracted with BERT to get a
document-level representation. Then, word embeddings are extracted
for N-gram words/phrases. Finally, we use cosine similarity to find the
words/phrases that are the most similar to the document.

The most similar words could then be identified as the words that
best describe the entire document.

"""
def __init__(self,
             model="all-MiniLM-L6-v2"):
    """ KeyBERT initialization

    Arguments:
        model: Use a custom embedding model.
               The following backends are currently supported
                  * SentenceTransformers
                  * Flair
                  * Spacy
                  * Gensim
                  * USE (TF-Hub)
                You can also pass in a string that points to one of the following
                sentence-transformers models:
                  * https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html
    """
    self.model = select_backend(model)

def extract_keywords(self,
                     docs: Union[str, List[str]],
                     candidates: List[str] = None,
                     keyphrase_ngram_range: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 1),
                     stop_words: Union[str, List[str]] = 'english',
                     top_n: int = 5,
                     min_df: int = 1,
                     use_maxsum: bool = False,
                     use_mmr: bool = False,
                     diversity: float = 0.5,
                     nr_candidates: int = 20,
                     vectorizer: CountVectorizer = None,
                     highlight: bool = False,
                     seed_keywords: List[str] = None) -> Union[List[Tuple[str, 
float]],
                                                                List[List[Tuple[str, 
 float]]]]:
    """ Extract keywords/keyphrases

    NOTE:
        I would advise you to iterate over single documents as they
        will need the least amount of memory. Even though this is slower,
        you are not likely to run into memory errors.

    Multiple Documents:
        There is an option to extract keywords for multiple documents
        that is faster than extraction for multiple single documents.

        However...this method assumes that you can keep the word embeddings
        for all words in the vocabulary in memory which might be troublesome.

        I would advise against using this option and simply iterating
        over documents instead if you have limited hardware.

    Arguments:
        docs: The document(s) for which to extract keywords/keyphrases
        candidates: Candidate keywords/keyphrases to use instead of extracting them 
  from the document(s)
        keyphrase_ngram_range: Length, in words, of the extracted keywords/keyphrases
        stop_words: Stopwords to remove from the document
        top_n: Return the top n keywords/keyphrases
        min_df: Minimum document frequency of a word across all documents
                if keywords for multiple documents need to be extracted
        use_maxsum: Whether to use Max Sum Similarity for the selection
                    of keywords/keyphrases
        use_mmr: Whether to use Maximal Marginal Relevance (MMR) for the
                 selection of keywords/keyphrases
        diversity: The diversity of the results between 0 and 1 if use_mmr
                   is set to True
        nr_candidates: The number of candidates to consider if use_maxsum is
                       set to True
        vectorizer: Pass in your own CountVectorizer from scikit-learn
        highlight: Whether to print the document and highlight
                   its keywords/keyphrases. NOTE: This does not work if
                   multiple documents are passed.
        seed_keywords: Seed keywords that may guide the extraction of keywords by
                       steering the similarities towards the seeded keywords

    Returns:
        keywords: the top n keywords for a document with their respective distances
                  to the input document

    """

    if isinstance(docs, str):
        keywords = self._extract_keywords_single_doc(doc=docs,
                                                     candidates=candidates,
                                                     
keyphrase_ngram_range=keyphrase_ngram_range,
                                                     stop_words=stop_words,
                                                     top_n=top_n,
                                                     use_maxsum=use_maxsum,
                                                     use_mmr=use_mmr,
                                                     diversity=diversity,
                                                     nr_candidates=nr_candidates,
                                                     vectorizer=vectorizer,
                                                     seed_keywords=seed_keywords)
        if highlight:
            highlight_document(docs, keywords)

        return keywords

    elif isinstance(docs, list):
        warnings.warn("Although extracting keywords for multiple documents is faster 
"
                      "than iterating over single documents, it requires 
 significantly more memory "
                      "to hold all word embeddings. Use this at your own 
 discretion!")
        return self._extract_keywords_multiple_docs(docs,
                                                    keyphrase_ngram_range,
                                                    stop_words,
                                                    top_n,
                                                    min_df,
                                                    vectorizer)

def _extract_keywords_single_doc(self,
                                 doc: str,
                                 candidates: List[str] = None,
                                 keyphrase_ngram_range: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 1),
                                 stop_words: Union[str, List[str]] = 'english',
                                 top_n: int = 5,
                                 use_maxsum: bool = False,
                                 use_mmr: bool = False,
                                 diversity: float = 0.5,
                                 nr_candidates: int = 20,
                                 vectorizer: CountVectorizer = None,
                                 seed_keywords: List[str] = None) -> List[Tuple[str, 
float]]:
    """ Extract keywords/keyphrases for a single document

    Arguments:
        doc: The document for which to extract keywords/keyphrases
        candidates: Candidate keywords/keyphrases to use instead of extracting them 
 from the document(s)
        keyphrase_ngram_range: Length, in words, of the extracted keywords/keyphrases
        stop_words: Stopwords to remove from the document
        top_n: Return the top n keywords/keyphrases
        use_mmr: Whether to use Max Sum Similarity
        use_mmr: Whether to use MMR
        diversity: The diversity of results between 0 and 1 if use_mmr is True
        nr_candidates: The number of candidates to consider if use_maxsum is set to 
True
        vectorizer: Pass in your own CountVectorizer from scikit-learn
        seed_keywords: Seed keywords that may guide the extraction of keywords by
                       steering the similarities towards the seeded keywords

    Returns:
        keywords: the top n keywords for a document with their respective distances
                  to the input document
    """
    try:
        # Extract Words
        if candidates is None:
            if vectorizer:
                count = vectorizer.fit([doc])
            else:
                count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=keyphrase_ngram_range, 
stop_words=stop_words).fit([doc])
            candidates = count.get_feature_names()

        # Extract Embeddings
        doc_embedding = self.model.embed([doc])
        candidate_embeddings = self.model.embed(candidates)

        # Guided KeyBERT with seed keywords
        if seed_keywords is not None:
            seed_embeddings = self.model.embed([" ".join(seed_keywords)])
            doc_embedding = np.average([doc_embedding, seed_embeddings], axis=0, 
 weights=[3, 1])

        # Calculate distances and extract keywords
        if use_mmr:
            keywords = mmr(doc_embedding, candidate_embeddings, candidates, top_n, 
diversity)
        elif use_maxsum:
            keywords = max_sum_similarity(doc_embedding, candidate_embeddings, 
candidates, top_n, nr_candidates)
        else:
            distances = cosine_similarity(doc_embedding, candidate_embeddings)
            keywords = [(candidates[index], round(float(distances[0][index]), 4))
                        for index in distances.argsort()[0][-top_n:]][::-1]

        return keywords
    except ValueError:
        return []

def _extract_keywords_multiple_docs(self,
                                    docs: List[str],
                                    keyphrase_ngram_range: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 1),
                                    stop_words: str = 'english',
                                    top_n: int = 5,
                                    min_df: int = 1,
                                    vectorizer: CountVectorizer = None) -> 
 List[List[Tuple[str, float]]]:
    """ Extract keywords/keyphrases for a multiple documents

    This currently does not use MMR and Max Sum Similarity as it cannot
    process these methods in bulk.

    Arguments:
        docs: The document for which to extract keywords/keyphrases
        keyphrase_ngram_range: Length, in words, of the extracted keywords/keyphrases
        stop_words: Stopwords to remove from the document
        top_n: Return the top n keywords/keyphrases
        min_df: The minimum frequency of words
        vectorizer: Pass in your own CountVectorizer from scikit-learn

    Returns:
        keywords: the top n keywords for a document with their respective distances
                  to the input document
    """
    # Extract words
    if vectorizer:
        count = vectorizer.fit(docs)
    else:
        count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=keyphrase_ngram_range, 
 stop_words=stop_words, min_df=min_df).fit(docs)
    words = count.get_feature_names()
    df = count.transform(docs)

    # Extract embeddings
    doc_embeddings = self.model.embed(docs)
    word_embeddings = self.model.embed(words)

    # Extract keywords
    keywords = []
    for index, doc in tqdm(enumerate(docs)):
        doc_words = [words[i] for i in df[index].nonzero()[1]]

        if doc_words:
            doc_word_embeddings = np.array([word_embeddings[i] for i in 
 df[index].nonzero()[1]])
            distances = cosine_similarity([doc_embeddings[index]], 
 doc_word_embeddings)[0]
            doc_keywords = [(doc_words[i], round(float(distances[i]), 4)) for i in 
 distances.argsort()[-top_n:]]
            keywords.append(doc_keywords)
        else:
            keywords.append(["None Found"])

    return keywords
```